# What firewall does Stack Exchange use?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know what firewall Stack Exchange uses? There was a post on the Serverfault blog [here](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/) that described it as:

- 1 Router / Firewall (Ubuntu Server)

Just curious to see what the bigger sites out there use.

Comment: These guys are hardcore, so I'm going to guess `pf`

Comment: I'm guessing pf as well..confirmation would be nice though.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is Ubuntu (Linux) the firewall is [Netfilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter).

Comment: That's just iptables isn't it?